# Check if an element is fading out (Javascript/Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, show-hide

is there a way to check if an element is currently fading out?

Something like this (Pseudo Code):

```
while(element.isFadingOut()){
//do something
}
```

The *isFadingOut()* is what I need here.
Does it exist somehow?

Comment: Please note you cannot check for async completion *in a loop* in Javascript as the fade occurs across multiple browser cycles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to check that something is already fading, you just need to check the css `opacity` value for anything less than 1.0:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vkcpknLh/

This is the required code as a jQuery extension:

```
$.fn.isFading = function(){
    return this.css('opacity') < 1;
};
```

**Note:** the fade is an asynchronous operation, so checking in a loop will never work. You would need to poll it via a timer etc (as per my JSFiddle).

The alternative is to use the completion event of `fadeOut`:

```
 element.fadeOut(function() {
       // do something on completion
 });
```

or use the animation `promise` provided for jQuery animation:

```
 element.fadeOut().promise().done(function(){
       // do something on completion of all animations for this element
 });
```

### Update:

Note: Some animation events do not fire `done` if the element was already in the final state. Use `always()` on the `promise` instead:

```
 element.fadeOut().promise().always(function(){
       // do something on completion of all animations for this element
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a trigger when you are actually fading out like so:

```
$(element).fadeOut("normal", function () {
// your other code
$(this).trigger('isFadingOut');
});
```

and the listen to this event somewhere else

```
$(element).on('myFadeOutEvent',function() {
// do something
});
```

replace the element with whatever you are using. Note: This would work if you are using JQuery